# Gutter between divs

Tags: html, css

See the following codepen for what I currently have: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjWYPO

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
    <div class="col-1-3" style="font-size:0px;">

        <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 1</div>
        <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 2</div>
        <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 3</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div> 
</div>
```

My question is, looking at the codepen, how do I create a gutter between the green cells. My research points to using negative margins and padding, but I cant get it to work at all.
Something like described here: http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

My requirements are, not! to create any more div's. I dont want to create a "row wrapper", i would really be happy if its solvable with the html that is in the current pen. I dont mind, and guess its part of the solution, to create a "row class" and apply it to the parent cell (here with id 'batman'), holding the green cells.

Second requirement is, that even though the codepen example uses 3 cells, that the solution works on any amount of cells. So it cant be using nth-child

and third, I would really really prefer to not! use flex to solve this problem.

Ignore the container class and the font-size:0 thing, its only a temporary fix to remove white space when using inline-block. My real code uses php minification.

I hope this make sense. Below is a picture how I want the result to look like: 
[image]

Would be grateful for any help,
thanks in advance!

==edit==

Added requirement to not use flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS and it should work (tested):

```
.bg-green {
  width: calc((100% - ((3 - 1)*2%))/(3/1));
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.bg-green:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Edited snippet:

```css
.container{
  font-size: 0;
}
[class|="col"] {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;

}
.col-1-3{
    width:calc(100%/(3/1));
}
.col-2-3{
    width:calc(100%/(3/2));
}
.col-1{
    width:100%;
}
.bg-blue{
    background-color:#42a5f5;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.bg-green{
    background-color:#66bb6a;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.bg-green {
  width: calc((100% - ((3 - 1)*2%))/(3/1));
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.bg-green:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
    <div class="col-1-3" style="font-size:0px;">

    <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 1</div>
        <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 2</div>
        <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 3</div>

  </div>
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
</div>
```

Just replace "3" with whatever numbers of columns you have and change the margin-right value as you like.

**Version with negative margin**

Change markup a little bit (similar structure to Bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-1-3">
  <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-1-3">
  <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
</div>
<div class="col-1-3">
  <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
</div>
```

And following part in CSS

```
.children-has-gutters > div {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-blue {
    background-color:#42a5f5;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:calc((100%/(3/1)) + 15px);
}
```

```css
.container{
  font-size: 0;
}
[class|="col"] {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;

}
.col-1-3{
 width:calc(100%/(3/1));
}
.col-2-3{
 width:calc(100%/(3/2));
}
.col-1{
 width:100%;
}

.children-has-gutters{
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-right:-15px;
  width: calc((100% / (3/1)) + 30px);
}
.children-has-gutters > div{
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.bg-blue{
 background-color:#42a5f5;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.bg-green{
 background-color:#66bb6a;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="col-1-3 children-has-gutters" style="font-size:0px;">
    
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
    </div>
      
  </div>
 <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
</div>
```

Note that you had to add 15px to each blue column, to avoid issue with container width. You can play around and check what happens without it - width of elements in container would be 100% - 30px (negative margin).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pawel, but I believe with this solution the cells wont be the same size. I have updated my question with a link to an article explaining the use of negative margins. Is there a way to use that instead?

Comment: I think that it will be possible, however you may run into some issues with % values and changing number of columns. Note that bootstrap is using px values. Totally doable, but not trivial. BTW I won't say that my solution above is the best ever, but it works for any number of columns, check out this pen with 6 columns https://codepen.io/paweljanicki/pen/QKpJdX

Comment: Im happy with px or em for the gutter, it doesnt have to be percentage. Actually, i think it would be preferred over percentage. Do you know how to do it with negative margin and padding? Still, thanks for your update, i will play around with it as well.

Comment: Something like this, but its obviously not working. But see the "children-has-gutters" class i have added: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGpxdL

Comment: Frank, I updated my answer. You can check how it works with negative margin.

Comment: Pawel, thank you! that is extremly close to what i want :)  - could I not apply the extra 30px to the element with "children-has-gutters" instead?

Comment: Yes, you can add .children-has-gutters {width: calc((100%/(3/1)) + 30px);} instead of adding 15px to blue columns

Comment: @FrankUnderwood I've just updated the code snippet, I think that now it's exactly what you wanted to achieve. Cheers!

Comment: Can I some how use :before and :after on the element with "children-has-gutters" instead to add the extra 15px? I think not, but figured I would ask :)

Comment: thanks for your help with this, long ago, I have found a bug, would be grateful if you could have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652229/gutter-between-divs-using-negative-margin-breaks

Answer (score 2):

I think adding this to your css, would do the job for you.

```
.col-1-3.bg-green{
    width:calc(100%/(3/1) - (3-1)*2px);
  margin:0px 2px;
}
```

Comment: There are 2 minor issues with your code, you are missing space here (3 - 1) and also margin is set both on the right and left. I think that Frank Underwood wanted only a gutter between green cells not green and blue.

Comment: Pawel is correct. The gutter is only between! green cells. And the use of 3 cells is only an example, it could be more than 3, or it could be using the col-2-3 class as well.

Answer (score 1):

you may select the second div and reset width and margins:

```
.col-1-3:nth-child(2) {
  margin:0 1em;
    width:calc(100% / (3/1) - 2em);
}
```

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
[class|="col"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: calc(100% / (3/1));
}
/* here update to overwrite width and add margins rules */
.col-1-3:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 1em;/* whatever , double it before taking it off from width */
  width: calc(100% / (3/1) - 2em);
}
/* end update */
.col-2-3 {
  width: calc(100%/(3/2));
}
.col-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: #42a5f5;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-green {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
  <div class="col-1-3" style="font-size:0px;">
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 1</div>
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
</div>
```

You may also want to take a look at display:flex :

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
[class|="col"] {
    flex:1;/* flex children, spray them evenly */
    font-size:20px;
}
.container .container .col-1-3:nth-child(2) {/* select second containere on second level */
  margin:0 1em;
}
.bg-blue{
 background-color:#42a5f5;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.bg-green{
 background-color:#66bb6a;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="col-1-3 container"><!-- here make it a flex container too -->
    
    <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 1</div>
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 2</div>
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-green">green 3</div>
      
  </div>
 <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
</div>
```

Codepen to play with https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEqQVg

#### edit

A third option, float + display:table, bg drawn via faux column . *This means to put right and left column in front of the middle container.*

```css
.container{
 background-color:#42a5f5;
  margin:1em 0;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px gray;
}
.bg-blue {
  width:33%;/* whatever how many of those ? */
 background-color:#42a5f5;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.float-l {
  float:left;
  margin-right:-15px;/* cause of border-spacing */
}
.float-r {
  float:right;
  margin-left:-15px;/* cause of border-spacing */
}
.child-container {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;/* suppose to spray cells evenly where no width is set to cells */
  background:linear-gradient(to left,#42a5f5 15px, transparent 15px),linear-gradient(to right,#42a5f5 15px, transparent 15px) white;/* reproduce blue bg part on white for both sides */
  width:calc(34% + 30px);
  margin:auto;
  border-spacing:15px 0;
}
.bg-green{
  display:table-cell;
 background-color:#66bb6a;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-l bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="float-r  bg-blue">blue right</div>
 <div class="child-container">    
    <div class=" bg-green">green 1</div>   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-l bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="float-r  bg-blue">blue right</div>
 <div class="child-container">    
    <div class=" bg-green">green 1</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 2</div>   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-l bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="float-r  bg-blue">blue right</div>
 <div class="child-container">    
    <div class=" bg-green">green 1</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 2</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 3</div>   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-l bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="float-r  bg-blue">blue right</div>
 <div class="child-container">    
    <div class=" bg-green">green 1</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 2</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 3</div>    
    <div class=" bg-green">green 4</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaAvjX

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer GCyrillus. But this solution will only work on my example of 3 cells, not if i decide to have 4 cells, or if i use the col-2-3 instead of a col-1-3. I have updated my question with a link to an article explaining the use of negative margins. Is there a way to use that instead? That would be absolute ideal for me :)

Comment: Also, i would prefer to keep using inline-block, and not flex. That would be ideal...

Comment: @FrankUnderwood Just saw your comments . What about using display:table and table-cell + pseudo instead inline-block (IE8 understands this) . Can you clarify what behavior should be seen when only one cell, two cells and four and more cells ?

Comment: @FrankUnderwood here is a guess https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaAvjX untill you clarify ;)

Comment: the behavior should be the same independent of how many cells there is. Thanks for the pen, there is some interesting code there which i definitely will look deeper into. Been working on and off today on this issue, and I think, at the moment what im looking for is how to let a div (a) who is inside another div (b) extend outside! its parent (b). If I could just make the child say 1em wider...any idea?

Comment: @FrankUnderwood i have not really an idea, i still do not understand what you exactly look for, you said  **_the behavior should be the same independent of how many cells there is_** ? obvious to you not to me . if one cell in te middle ? gutter or not ? how many blue and green possible, any max or min width, and so on :)

Comment: Sorry. don't focus on the colors, they are just for illustration. Any cell (lets call it parent) can have any amount of children. These children should all have a gutter between! them. Which causes a problem with the first and last usually, if using padding on all children, and then removing padding on first and last (the width of all children is then not the same). Hence why i would prefer to do it similar to bootstrap, where they use the negative margin to hide the first and last child's padding. Anyway, this is getting confusing lol, so don't worry, you have been very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
 display:flex;
  
  
  
}
.container > div{
  flex-grow:1
}
[class|="col"] {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;

}
.col-1-3{
 
}
.col-2-3{
 
}
.col-1{
 
}
.bg-blue{
 background-color:#42a5f5;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.bg-green{
 background-color:#66bb6a;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.bg-green+ .bg-green{ margin-left:20px}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-blue">blue left</div>


  <div class=" bg-green">green 1</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 2</div>
  <div class=" bg-green">green 3</div>
  


  <div class=" bg-blue">blue right</div>
</div>
```

Something like this? 
This is using flexbox layout. If you want more browser compatibility then I think a good option would be use any css framework.

Comment: Thank you for your answer link2pk, much appreciated. One thing though, (i will update my question), I prefer not to use flex at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: then you have to use any CSS framework like bootstrap, foundation, materializecss etc

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of much help :p , please let me know once you found a solution.