# percentage + px width of DIVS wrapping when resizing browser

Tags: css

In the following SO question ([Gutter between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685497/gutter-between-divs)), I got a great answer from Paweł Janicki. That was almost 4 months ago and I just revisited the code where I used it, and realized that in IE 11, when you resize the window, it doesn't stay on one line, it seem while! resizing the IE window, it goes from one line, and then wraps, goes back to one line, and then wraps.....

Here are two pictures of how it looks. In the first picture it looks perfect, then I minimize the window and it breaks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QcaO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbwlM.png

and here is the codepen with the sample:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgZMwq

I would be ever so grateful if someone could help me fix this behavior in IE as it works as I want it in FF and Chrome.

thanks in advance!

Below is the final code I got from the old SO question:

```css
    .container{
      font-size: 0;
    }
    [class|="col"] {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position:relative;
        font-size:20px;

    }
    .col-1-3{
     width:calc(100%/(3/1));
    }
    .col-2-3{
     width:calc(100%/(3/2));
    }
    .col-1{
     width:100%;
    }

    .children-has-gutters{
      margin-left:-15px;
      margin-right:-15px;
      width: calc((100% / (3/1)) + 30px);
    }
    .children-has-gutters > div{
      padding-left:15px;
      padding-right:15px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    .bg-blue{
     background-color:#42a5f5;
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    .bg-green{
     background-color:#66bb6a;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
     <div class="col-1-3 children-has-gutters" style="font-size:0px;">
        
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
        </div>
          
      </div>
     <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's because of the usage of `font-size:0` in `.container` & `.children-has-gutters` div. Remove these & reduce the calculated % width applied on `.children-has-gutters`. You should be good to go - IE acts weird with the whole "**use font-size:0 to kill the white space**" workarounds.

Comment: The font-size:0 is a fix for default white space between inline-block elements, and is needed. Else it wraps in all browsers. This issue I only notice when resizing IE 11 browser. If you have IE, could you try please?

Comment: The font-size:1 fix is only for this css+html only example. On my machine I actually use the following php code to fix the white space issue. the problem is on both solutions, but only in IE: ob_start(function($html) {return preg_replace('/>\s+</','><',$html);});

Answer (score 0):

Try flex solution

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  }
    .col-1-3{
      flex:1;

    }
```

```css
   .container{
      font-size: 0;
    }
    [class|="col"] {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position:relative;
        font-size:20px;

    }

  .container{
  display:flex;
  }
    .col-1-3{
      flex:1;
     
    }
    .col-2-3{
     
    }
    .col-1{
     width:100%;
    }

    .children-has-gutters{
      margin-left:-15px;
      margin-right:-15px;
     
    }
    .children-has-gutters > div{
      padding-left:15px;
      padding-right:15px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    .bg-blue{
     background-color:#42a5f5;
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    .bg-green{
     background-color:#66bb6a;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
     <div class="col-1-3 children-has-gutters" style="font-size:0px;">
        
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
        </div>
          
      </div>
     <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I need to keep it inline-block. Any solution without flex?

Answer (score 0):

in the unlikely even that someone else stumble on this same problem, the answer is:

This line of code, has two calculations, first the percentage and then the addition of px:

```
width: calc((100% / (3/1)) + 30px);
```

IE 11 seem not to be able to handle it, and gets it wrong when! you resize the browser, the answer is to calculate the percentage yourself, like this:

```
width: calc(33.333% + 30px);
```

Thats it, flickering gone.