# Gutter between DIVs using negative margin breaks

Tags: css

I have the below code, which works fine. As you can see, it creates a gutter between the 3 green elements, which are children of the second out of three blue elements.

```css
.container{
  font-size: 0;
}
[class|="col"] {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;

}
.col-1-3{
 width:calc(100%/(3/1));
}
.col-2-3{
 width:calc(100%/(3/2));
}
.col-1{
 width:100%;
}

.children-has-gutters{
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-right:-15px;
  width: calc((100% / (3/1)) + 30px);
}
.children-has-gutters > div{
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.bg-blue{
 background-color:#42a5f5;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.bg-green{
 background-color:#66bb6a;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue left</div>
 <div class="col-1-3 children-has-gutters" style="font-size:0px;">
    
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
    </div>
      
  </div>
 <div class="col-1-3 bg-blue">blue right</div>
</div>
```

In the below example, there is only one blue element, not three. And suddenly, the gutter between its green child elements doesnt work as expected. Sure, it has space in between, but it creates a horizontal scroller on the page, and the left most and right most side get the gutter as well, somehow seem like the negative margin doesnt work.
I would be grateful if someone could point out what breaks compared to the above code.

```css
.container{
  font-size: 0;
}
[class|="col"] {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;

}
.col-1-3{
 width:calc(100%/(3/1));
}
.col-2-3{
 width:calc(100%/(3/2));
}
.col-1{
 width:100%;
}

.children-has-gutters{
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-right:-15px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
.children-has-gutters > div{
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.bg-blue{
 background-color:#42a5f5;
 color:#ffffff;
}
.bg-green{
 background-color:#66bb6a;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-1 bg-blue children-has-gutters" style="font-size:0px;">
    
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
    </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

So, color wise it should go: left edge of screen, green 1, blue gap, green 2, blue gap, green 3, right edge of screen.

This is just an example, the number of children can change, so its not always 3.
This question is a follow up question to an old question of mine, as I now found this bug and cant figure out the problem:

[old question here >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685497/gutter-between-divs)

Requirements: I dont want to add new div elements, and I dont want to change to flexbox.

Comment: Confused by the HTML. Why do you have divs for just the colors? Why not just add the colors to the col divs and then put those cols in one container that has the background you want?

Comment: yeah sorry, but this is just as an example, to show with colours what im trying to achieve. Which is gutters between divs.

Comment: Your culprit is the `width: calc(100% + 30px);`, but I'm not sure what you're going for... is it something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kL9r7tp8/ ?

Comment: @Winter thanks for your reply. Regarding your jsfiddle, yes but without the blue on the very ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ugly hack, but you could put overflow hidden on your container to get rid of the blue on the edges:

```
.container{
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just don't see any reason for the negative margins and the `calc` width for the class `...has-gutters` what you can do is just add a `padding-right` except for the `last-child`

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}

[class|="col"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: calc(100%/(3/1));
}

.col-2-3 {
  width: calc(100%/(3/2));
}

.col-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.children-has-gutters>div {
  padding-right: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.children-has-gutters>div:last-child {
  padding-right:0;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #42a5f5;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1 bg-blue children-has-gutters" style="font-size:0px;">
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="bg-green">green 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The code in my question is just as example, in the original the children might be more than 3, and span more than one row, so I wont know which is the last one. I have edited my question with a link to my old question this is based on.

Comment: @FrankUnderwood ok, that will be tricky the best will be jump to flexbox... I have a question which will be the expected output if there is for example 5 elements each one of 1/3 of the width ?  the last two on a new row both aligned to left ? or the last one always aligned to right ?

Comment: correct, two lines both aligned to the left. I dont want to move to flexbox, but I might just have to...which defeats the purpose of a lot of other code that this is part of :(